# Read next word in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a text file that has following content:

```
ac und
accipio annehmen
ad zu
adeo hinzugehen
...
```

I read the text file and iterate through the lines:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("translate.txt"));
while(sc.hasNext()){
 String line = sc.nextLine();       
}
```

Each line has two words. Is there any method in java to get the next word or do I have to split the line string to get the words?

Comment: Your while loop should read  `while(sc.hasNextLine()){`

Comment: Is this a german/latin vocable trainer?

Comment: yes, a little exercise on using files and hashmaps

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You do not necessarily have to split the line because java.util.Scanner's default delimiter is whitespace.

You can just create a new Scanner object within your while statement.

```
    Scanner sc2 = null;
    try {
        sc2 = new Scanner(new File("translate.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
    while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {
        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(sc2.nextLine());
        while (s2.hasNext()) {
            String s = s2.next();
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to store the words in a hashmap, so each iteration of the second loop should cover to words. is it possible to have s1.next() twice and do something like that: map.put(s1.next(), s1.next())?

Comment: Yes, that should work as long as your file's formatting is correct.

Answer (score 16):

You already get the next line in this line of your code:

```
 String line = sc.nextLine();
```

To get the words of a line, I would recommend to use:

```
String[] words = line.split(" ");
```

Comment: is it possible to apply a scanner to the line and scan the line using next?

Comment: Yes then you should modifiy your while loop: while(sc.hasNextLine())

Answer (score 7):

Using `Scanner`s, you will end up spawning a lot of objects for every line. You will generate a decent amount of garbage for the GC with large files. Also, it is nearly three times slower than using split().

On the other hand, If you split by space (`line.split(" ")`), the code will fail if you try to read a file with a different whitespace delimiter. If `split()` expects you to write a regular expression, and it does matching anyway, use `split("\\s")` instead, that matches a "bit" more whitespace than just a space character.

P.S.: Sorry, I don't have right to comment on already given answers.

Answer (score 4):

you're better off reading a line and then doing a split.

```
File file = new File("path/to/file");
String words[]; // I miss C
String line;
HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8")))
{
    while((line = br.readLine() != null)){
        words = line.split("\\s");
        if (hm.containsKey(words[0])){
                System.out.println("Found duplicate ... handle logic");
        }
        hm.put(words[0],words[1]); //if index==0 is ur key
    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @Gab ... in no-time, you will land a Java job :)

Answer (score 4):

You can just use Scanner to read word by word, Scanner.next() reads the next word

```
try {
  Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(filename));

  while (s.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("word:" + s.next());
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("Error accessing input file!");
}
```