# Java Scanner: NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am having trouble getting my `Scanner` to work.  It is based on an example my teacher gave us to modify, but I keep getting errors when I run it. When I run it I get this error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
at ReadDataFile.main(ReadDataFile.java:25)
```

Main Class:

```
  /**
 * Write a description of class ReadDataFile here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ReadDataFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner sInputFile=null;
        String FirstName,LastName;
        Float PayRate, HoursWorked;

        ArrayList<Employee> Records = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        try {
            sInputFile = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:\\temp\\inputData.txt")));
            while (sInputFile.hasNextLine()) {
               FirstName = new String(sInputFile.next());
               if(FirstName.length() > 9)
               FirstName = FirstName.substring(0,8);
               LastName = new String(sInputFile.next());
               if(LastName.length() > 9)
               LastName = LastName.substring(0,8);
               PayRate = sInputFile.nextFloat();
               HoursWorked = sInputFile.nextFloat();
               Employee worker = new Employee(LastName,FirstName,PayRate,HoursWorked);
               Records.add(worker);
            } // while   

        } // try
        catch(Exception IOException)
        {
           System.out.println("Unknown file error occurred ...");
        }
        finally { sInputFile.close();}

        System.out.print("Complete");
    } // main
} // class
```

Employee Class:

```
public class Employee
{
  String LastName, FirstName;
  float PayRate, HoursWorked, Net, Gross, Tax, TaxRate;

  public Employee(String LN, String FN, float Rate, float Hours) 
  {
    LastName = LN;
    FirstName = FN;
    PayRate = Rate;
    HoursWorked = Hours;
    Gross = PayRate * HoursWorked;
    Net = Gross * (1-TaxRate);
    Tax = Gross * TaxRate;

  }

  public float getPayRate()
  {
      return PayRate;
    }
    public float getHoursWorked()
  {
      return HoursWorked;
    }
    public float getNet()
  {
      return Net;
    }
    public float getGross()
  {
      return Gross;
    }
    public String getLastName()
  {
      return LastName;
    }
    public String getFirstName()
  {
      return FirstName;
    }
  public float getTax()
  {
      return Tax;
    }
}
```

Here is the text I am trying to read:

```
 Doe   John  13.00  44.5
 Doe   John  13.00  44.5
 Doe   John  13.00  44.5
 Doe   John  13.00  44.5
```

Comment: Does the file you're trying to read have any data in it?  `next` is going to read the whole chunk of data not including the newline character, so I'd expect it to fail if all you have in the file is a newline character.

Comment: Where's line 25 in `ReadDataFile`. BTW, it might be more robust to read, then parse, the line as a single entity.

Comment: Line 25 is: FirstName = new String(sInputFile.next());

Comment: And the file I'm trying to read is a text file with the data at the end of my first post in it.

Comment: Your text file has trailing empty lines, remove them.

Comment: There's a bunch of "best practice" things in here, single line ifs are a no no, use camel casing for your fields (which should also be private), calculate your values for the getters on the fly rather than setting in the constructor, reducing fields and neatening the code.

Comment: Have a look here for some info about Scanners: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574041/read-next-word-in-java

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `Scanner.nextLine()` at the bottom of the loop, i.e. in this case `sInputFile.nextLine()`. You aren't advancing to the next line, so you run out of tokens on this line.

Comment: I tried adding it to the bottom of the while loop, but it says "non-static method nextLine() cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: @rcdude I gave you the name of the method you should call. It isn't static so you should call it on your `Scanner` *instance.*

Comment: `You aren't advancing to the next line, so you run out of tokens on this line` Neither `#next` or `#nextFloat` care about lines or any other whitespace character. But they care if there are empty lines at the bottom of the text file. `sInputFile.hasNextLine()` would return true here, but  `sInputFile.next()` wouldn't find anything to read, hence the exception. So I still think, my comment `Your text file has trailing empty lines, remove them.` might be the solution here, but I guess OP ignored it? :D

Answer (score -2):

This will work..

```
try {
       //input File
        sInputFile = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/Alex.hp/Desktop/t.txt"));

        while (sInputFile.hasNextLine()) { //your code
           FirstName = new String(sInputFile.next());
           if(FirstName.length() > 9)
           FirstName = FirstName.substring(0,8);
           LastName = new String(sInputFile.next());
           if(LastName.length() > 9)
           LastName = LastName.substring(0,8);
           PayRate =Float.parseFloat(sInputFile.next()); //edited cause of Exception(InputMismatch Error)
           HoursWorked =Float.parseFloat(sInputFile.next()); //edited cause of Exception(InputMismatch Error)
           Employee worker = new Employee(LastName,FirstName,PayRate,HoursWorked);
           Records.add(worker);
        } // while   

    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

//See the results
 for(int i=0; i<Records.size(); i++)
        System.out.println(Records.get(i).FirstName+"    "+Records.get(i).LastName +" " +Records.get(i).PayRate +" "+Records.get(i).HoursWorked);
```

[image]

Comment: He isn't getting a ' type mismatch error', and, if he was, all this would accomplish would be to change it to a `NumberFormatException.`

Comment: All your edit proves is that you were using different input from the OP. And don't post pictures of text here, it's a complete waste of everybody's bandwidth.

Comment: @EJP i used the Scanner as the user and then as shown in my answer and i got that error why it is so strange for you and why me to lie?