# Using HashSet to store a text file and read from it

Tags: java, string, set

I've seen a lot of great resources regarding HasSets, but nothing that helps me with this particular problem. I'm taking an algorithms class on generics and this assignment requires a txt file to be read into the system using Scanner (which is done) and using a hashSet, load the txt file so that I can read it with user input and find the number of occurrences of the word. i have the method for returning words and I have most of the hashSet and file reader code done. But I'm completely stuck on how to store the whole txt file as one hashSet. i couldn't get it to work by doing crime.add and i tried several other things. Am I missing an easier way to implement this method?  Thanks

Edit: assignment instructions - 
Program 1 (70 points)
Load a java.util.HashSet with the the words from the novel “Crime and Punishment”, by
Theodore Dostoevsky (text file available on Blackboard with this assignment). Prompt the user to
enter a word and report whether or not that word appears in the novel.

Edit: Ok, I have all of this written and it runs but it is not finding words that are definitely in the txt file, so somewhere I went wrong adding the file into the hashSet. Any ideas? I've tried with array list, different String implementations and I just don't know where to turn. Thanks for any helpful info.

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class CandPHashSet {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("crime_and_punishment.txt")).useDelimiter("[ˆa-zA-Z]+");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Set<String> crime = new HashSet<String>();

        while(file.hasNext()){
            String line = file.nextLine();
            //String[] words = line.split("[ˆa-zA-Z]+");
            for (String word : line.split("[ˆa-zA-Z]+")){
                crime.add(line);
            }
        }

        String search;
        System.out.println("Enter a word to search for: ");
        search = input.next();

        if(crime.contains(input)){
            System.out.println("Yes");
        }else{
            System.out.println("No");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've gotten it this far, but it still looks like I'm not adding it properly....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you don't need to count the word occurrences. You just need to *split* the input file string into individual words, and store them into a `HashSet<String>`. Then you should use the method `contains()` to check if a word given by the user is present in the set.

There are a couple of problems in your code that you should check:

- The way you use `useDelimiter()` in the `Scanner` is not correct. You probably don't want to specify a delimiter so that *whitespace*, the default, will be used.
- If you are using *whitespace* as the scanner delimiter it will already split your input as words. So we don't need to read the file line by line.
- You use `crime.contains(input)` to look for the user provided word. But `input` is a `Scanner`, not a `String`. You want to use `crime.contains(search)`.

The revised code would look somewhat like this:

```
// Read the file using whitespace as a delimiter (default)
// so that the input will be split into words
Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("crime_and_punishment.txt"));

Set<String> crime = new HashSet<>();
// For each word in the input
while (file.hasNext()) {
    // Convert the word to lower case, trim it and insert into the set
    // In this step, you will probably want to remove punctuation marks
    crime.add(file.next().trim().toLowerCase());
}

System.out.println("Enter a word to search for: ");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
// Also convert the input to lowercase
String search = input.next().toLowerCase();

// Check if the set contains the search string
if (crime.contains(search)) {
    System.out.println("Yes");
} else {
    System.out.println("No");
}
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you, that was my fault as i combined the two programs. The counting comes in on the map assignment. But the problem I'm having is loading the text file into hashSet<String> As you see, i create the hashSet and i read in the file but I can't seem to find a valid way to actually add the file as a string

Comment: Ah, that makes since. I'll mess with that for a while, thank you so much!

Comment: Hey Sorry I got through some more but I'm having an issue splitting this thing still. I'm editing the code to reflect these changes, but why exactly am I not able to do this line by line and load it into the set? I'm lost here somewhere

Comment: Now it is working, but I checked the file and it definitely contains the word "The" many times, but the program says "no". Should I split words differently now, or does this seem like an issue with adding the file?

Comment: I made it a bit simpler now. A good tip would be to place a System.out.println(crime) after the loop to check the set contents. Then you can see if the word you're looking for is really in there.

Answer (score 5):

You are posting conflicting requirements.

> find the number of occurrences

is not the same as

> report whether or not that word appears in the novel.

HashSet works fine for this second one.  Not for the first.

Be very careful when reading requirements.  5 extra minutes reading them can save you 5 extra hours writing code.

To follow the instructions what you need to do is add one word at a time to your hash set.  Reading one word at a time already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4574063/1493294)

Whenever I'm unsure what container to use I look at this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with a `HashSet.` You will just lose the duplicates. You can count t the duplicates as you add them, but then you need somewhere to put the counts.

A `Map<String, Integer>` is required.

Comment: i have done it with a map, but this new assignment must be done with a HashSet

Comment: As stated it is impossible. I suggest you post the actual wording of the assignment, not a vague restatement of it. Edit it into your question.

Comment: Oh man, sorry EJP, i was combing assignments. The count was meant for the mapping project, you're right. My apologies!