# How to separate excel file by rows and paste them into variables?

Tags: java, arrays, excel, csv, file-io

This is my excel (.csv) file:

[image: Excel file]

I was wondering if there was a way to  separate it into rows and save them each into arrays based on their respected variables. I attempted it here but it's not really doing what I want.

```
try{
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("PeriodicTableData.csv"));
    reader.nextLine();
    for(int i =0 ; reader.hasNext();i++){
        ele[i]= reader.nextLine();
        atomicnumber[i] = reader.nextLine();
        symbol[i] = reader.nextLine();
        bp[i] = reader.nextLine();
        mp[i] = reader.nextLine();
        density[i] = reader.nextLine();
    }
    reader.close();
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("File not found!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With what you have written there you might consider reading in one line at a time:

[How to read a single word (or line) from a text file Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31370940/how-to-read-a-single-word-or-line-from-a-text-file-java)

then splitting your line based on commas using String.split() and then assigning the resultant array in a way similar to what you had before

Here's an example that *should* work:

```
    try{
      Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("PeriodicTableData.csv"));
      reader.nextLine();
      for(i=0;reader.hasNext();i++) {
            String line = reader.nextLine();
            String[] values = line.split(",");
            //the above will take your input line and split 
            //values based on the passed character in quotes 

            ele[i]= values[0];
            atomicnumber[i] = values[1];
            symbol[i] = values[2];
            bp[i] = values[3];
            mp[i] = values[4];
            density[i] = values[5];
     }
    reader.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
     System.out.println("File not found!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with i would say that you probably want to change the arrays to arrayList:s if you dont know the numbers of rows. Then nextLine gives you a new line and not the next cell. So i would do something similar to this

```
ArrayList<String> ele = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> atomicnumber = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> symbol = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> bp = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> mp = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> density = new ArrayList<>();
try{
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("PeriodicTableData.csv"));
    reader.nextLine();
    for(int i =0 ; reader.hasNext();i++){
        String line = reader.nextLine();
        ele.add( line.split(";")[0]);
        atomicnumber.add( line.split(";")[1]);
        //and so on

    }
    reader.close();
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File not found!");
}
```

Note that however i assumes that it is an comma-delimited file ... If not, you'll need a separate excel library.