# A separate class that returns a String array in android application?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I just wanted to know how to write a class that returns a `String` array.
Here are the things or flow of work, if you will.

1) I have a text file in raw/ folder

2) I will read this text file at the app startup.

3) The process of reading the text file would be done through a class in the question.

4) So the class I'm asking for has no other task, but to load the text file, read it and return String array to the MainActivity.

5) In `MainActivity`, I will access the `*that* array's` elements like this or so ...

```
String test = returnedArray[i];
```

So, let's have the content of the text in raw folder be:
one two three four ...

The class I asked will read those `String(s)` and will return a `String array` that looks like this:
`{"one","two","three","four" ... }` `// a complete array type.`

So the main thing I want to know is the structure of the class.

The second thing is:

In what format ...For example... one,two,three,four ... or 
one|two|three|four ... etc ) should I write in the text file so that the 
process of the class reading and returning the String array be as easily as possible?

The one thing I don't want to do is `writing directly array forma`t into the text file and load and read it.

I think I have mapped out my question clearly.

I'm in the process of learning java basic.

EDIT:
Actually I'm trying it myself now: Here are the codes snippets: I can load the file and display at a textview. But kind of lost how to return a string array from there. Please not this is done in the MainActivity.I'm wondering and asking if I can do it in a seperate class.

/////////////
private StringBuilder myFunction(Context context) throws IOException 
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method

```
        final Resources resources =  context.getResources();
        InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.texttext);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             strBuild.append(line);
                }




        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
        return strBuild; 

}
```

/////////////

Comment: It is possible if that is what you are asking

Comment: Please note: stackoverflow is not a place where you drop **requirements** and other people drop code. We help with specific problems, so the very first thing for you: try it yourself; and/or post the code that you have already written.

Comment: Create a class that has this function. Store the array in a field and create a getter for it. In mainactiity initialize it and get it from there. Or just call the method directly having it public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you could do it. It's just to show you, improve it :)

```
 public class ReadFileToList{ 

    private final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private final Context context;

    public ReadFileToList(Context context){
        this.context = context;

        myFunction();
    }

    private void myFunction() throws IOException { 

        final Resources resources =  context.getResources();
        InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.texttext);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                list.add(line);
            }




        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
        return list; 
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getList(){
        return list;
    }
}
```

In MainActivity use:

```
ReadFileToList rftl = new ReadFileToList(getApplicationContext());
ArrayList<String> list = rftl.getList();
```

Comment: Well done! I need such a raw idea or structure how to achieve this. You got the point there. :) Sure I can improve this. Thanks for your time taken to get the pilot structure for me.

Comment: You're welcome mate. Remember to accept an answer when your done :)

Comment: Done with a great grin like this :D

Answer (score 0):

If the data you're storing are just simple one-line strings, the most convenient way to store them is separating them by newline - it is easily readable for you as a user/developer, and reading a line is a relatively easy operation compared to reading a portion of a file up until an arbitrary delimiter (not to mention escaping rules).

For reading the whole file, you can use [FileUtils.readLines](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines(java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)).

Answer (score 0):

Put your strings each on a new line this way you can separate them when reading. Furthermore you ll have to read the file and add each line  (string) to the array or better arraylist since you might not know the array size inbefore.

I suggest you read upon reading files from asset folder and collections.
Try something and post issues you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the file and put every word in a different array spot?
1-read the file whit a BufferedReader and a FileReader
2-save the readed line like single word using

```
String line = File.nextLine();
String[] words = line.split("separator");
```

3- now you have all the words in the array, you have just to find a way to memorize them in the correct way.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommand using the Scanner class to parse your input file:

```
Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("raw/yourfile.txt"));
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
     vector.add(sc.nextLine());
}
String[] rerValue = vector.toArray(new String[vector.size()]);
```

You can find more information about the Scanner class and its usage on stackoverflow:

[Read next word in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574041/read-next-word-in-java)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12899164)

Comment: @JBL Thanx for the advice, I edited my post and added some example code