# Count number of words from file converted to string

Tags: java, io

I am trying to count the number of words in a file passed through a string. I am also displaying the string to make sure the output is correct and I am getting the exact contents of the file.

However, my word count method counts the last word of the previous line and the first word of the next line as one word.

Example: "Test word (newline) test words" outputs as "Test wordtest words"

Tried adding "\n" to my code and it displays correct output now but still counts it as before.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your `countWords` method, you are only incrementing the count when you see spaces.  Increment the count when you see newlines (`\n`) as well.

Comment: Another way to do that is using [BreakIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html)

Comment: Assuming this isn't an assignment, you can also use the String#split method to split the line into tokens and count them. (`line.split("\\b");`).

Comment: You can also use `line.charAt(i).isWhitespace()` to detect multiple types of spaces (newlines, tabs, etc.).

Comment: This topic will help you to count words in a file. [Read next word in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574041/read-next-word-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

You can change the condition that checks for spaces to include new line too

```
if ((line.charAt(i) == ' ' || line.charAt(i) == '\n') && line.charAt(i + 1) != ' ')
```

Comment: There is a bug in this condition though that the last word may not be counted or " \n \n \n \n " results in multiple words

Comment: @toongeorges That's why the OPs solution starts the count at 1, not 0.

Comment: However, I suppose that trick/hack may yield an incorrect count if the text consists only of a word followed by a space.

Comment: @David Choweller you are right, but then the code counts one word too much when the second last character is a space or new line and the last character is a new line

Comment: @toongeorges Correct.

Comment: To be fair, that problem is not with this answer, but with the OPs solution.  This answer is just correcting a particular problem with the OPs original solution involving correctly identifying word boundaries.

Comment: @DavidChoweller that's right. There are other answers that shows how to do word counting properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
 /* * Counting number of words using regular expression. */
public int countWord(String word) {
    return word.isEmpty() ? 0 : word.split("\\s+").length;
}
```

Comment: i just added a similar answer, but yours is even more elegant

Comment: I tried your code but got 1 extra word returned and not sure why. (you don't have to answer back I found another fix).

Answer (score 0):

You can also count using regular expressions.

```
public static int countWords(String line) {

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
    Matcher  matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

    int count = 0;
    while (matcher.find())
        count++;

    return count;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the reason why "Test word (newline) test words" outputs as "Test wordtest words"

in.nextLine() returns the line as a String excluding the newline character at end of the line. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--

It would be more efficient though to keep track of the word count instead of appending the lines to a String and then counting at the end.  The pseudocode would be something like this:

```
int wordCount = 0
while (file has more lines) {
    line = line.trim()
    int wordsOnLine = numberOfSpacesPlusOne(line)
    wordCount += wordsOnLine
}
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention it is for an assignment and we are required to pass it into a string.

Comment: No problem :)  You may want to use a StringBuilder instead of a String.  Every time you do a String concatenation (line += ..), a new String is created.  Your code would be something like this with a StringBuilder:

    `StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
    int lines = 0;
    while(in.hasNextLine()){
        lines++;
        line.append("\n").append(in.nextLine());
    }
    ...
    int words = countWords(line.toString());`

Comment: Thanks for the input. Helps me through this class more than you think :)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just

```
String sentence = "This is a sentence.";
String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
System.out.println(words.length);
```

split your string at the " " and count the words.