# Reading a text file (~90,000 words) and trying to add each word into an ArrayList of strings

Tags: java, string, arraylist, filereader, tokenize

My method read and prints the file, but I am having trouble adding each word to the `ArrayList dict`.

The reader reads the file one char at a time, so what I have written adds each char to `dict`: [c,a,t,d,o,g] when I want [cat,dog]. The text file has the words on their own line; how can I distinguish them?

My code so far:

```
public static List Dictionary() {
    ArrayList <String> dict = new ArrayList <String>(); 

    File inFile = new File("C:/Users/Aidan/Desktop/fua.txt");   
    FileReader ins = null;

    try {
        ins = new FileReader(inFile);

        int ch;

        while ((ch = ins.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char) ch);

            dict.add((char) ch + "");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            ins.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return dict;
}
```

Comment: suppose there are good examples and approaches to solve this issue. refer following [post](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please observe Java naming conventions, so `readDictionary` instead of `Dictionary` (which looks like a class name). Next, I would pass the `fileName` into the method (instead of hard-coding the path in your method). Instead of reinventing the wheel, I would use a [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). You can also use the `try-with-resources` instead of `finally` here (and the diamond operator). Like,

```
public static List<String> readDictionary(String fileName) {
    List<String> dict = new ArrayList<>();

    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(fileName))) {
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            dict.add(scan.next());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.printf("Caught Exception: %s%n", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dict;
}
```

*Alternatively*, use a `BufferedReader` and `split` each word yourself. Like,

```
public static List<String> readDictionary(String fileName) {
    List<String> dict = new ArrayList<>();

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                new File(fileName)))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                Stream.of(line.split("\\s+"))
                        .forEachOrdered(word -> dict.add(word));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.printf("Caught Exception: %s%n", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dict;
}
```

But that is basically what the first example does.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer here which shows how to use Scanner to get words from a file: [Read next word in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574041/read-next-word-in-java).

Instead of printing out the words, you'd want to append them to an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

As the `read` method of the `FileReader` can only read a single character at a time and that's *not* what you want, then I would suggest you use a `Scanner` to read the file.

```
ArrayList<String> dict = new ArrayList<>(); 
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/Aidan/Desktop/fua.txt"));
while(scanner.hasNext()){
     dict.add(scanner.next());   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `FileReader` in a `BufferedReader`, which has a `readLine()` method that will get you an entire line (word) at a time.  `readLine()` returns `null` when there are no more lines to read.