# Adding a ";" after each piece of data in Arraylist

Tags: java

I wrote a program to make my text file data like `CSV` format.

```java
static String originalFileContent = "";

static BufferedReader reader; 

static BufferedWriter writer;


public static void main(String[] args)   {
        
        String input = args[1];
        String output = args[2];
    
        for(int i = 0; i<args.length; i++) {
           System.out.println("args[" + i + "]: " + args[i]);
        }
        
        try {
            readInput(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            createLogic();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            writeOutput(output);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
                
}
    
public static void readInput(String input) throws IOException {
        
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));
        
        String currentReadingLine;
        currentReadingLine = reader.readLine();
        
        while (currentReadingLine != null) {
            
            originalFileContent += currentReadingLine; //-
            currentReadingLine = reader.readLine();   
              //String
        }
}
    
public static void createLogic() throws Exception  {
            
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
            String str = ";";

            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
                list.add(str);
            }
            String format = "Name; Strasse; Ort" + System.lineSeparator();
            originalFileContent = format;
            int a = 1;
            for(String textString: list) {
                originalFileContent += textString;
                
                if(a%4 == 0) {
                 originalFileContent += System.lineSeparator();
                }
                a++;
            }
            list.add(";");
}
    
public static void writeOutput(String output) throws IOException {
        
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(output));
        writer.write(originalFileContent);
        writer.close();
        
}
```

I got the Output:

> Name; Strasse; Ort
>
> Max Amillion. 1234 South
>
> John Doe. 4321 West
>
> Mary Poppins. 101 Park
>
> Acme Manufacturing Co. 9001 Main

but I would like to have a `;` in between each piece of data anybody now how to make this possible ?

Comment: `originalFileContent += textString + ";";`?

Comment: You should not post personal information here...

Comment: What is the purpose of `readInput()`? It read in the entire content of some text file, concatenating all the lines into a single line, storing it in static field `originalFileContent`. Then `createLogic()` discards all that by replacing the value, so what was the point?

Comment: Hello i respect private iformation but if you check the adress there is no found street to the postal code so they are just made up.

Comment: @EnricoGabellone For fun I googled the first and last entry. And indeed I found the person in the first case and the company in the second case. You just concatenated the house number and the postcode, which was not hard to see. **That's not so nice.** For your question you could have just used "Foo Bar; Baz Street 12345" or any other random string.

Answer (score 0):

```
        if(a%4 == 0) {
         originalFileContent += System.lineSeparator();
        } else {
         originalFileContent += ";";
        }
```

(Incidentally, you should really use a complex data type, i. e. a class, to represent each row of data.)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things going on that are wrong (some are arguable...). I'll work from the top down to try and piece things together.

### `main(String[] args)`

This one is an arguable fix: In your main method, you have three individual try/catch blocks which essentially do the same thing - try, and print the stack trace on error. You can compress these to one block:

```java
try {
  readInput(input); // Huh?
  createLogic();
  writeOutput(output);
} catch(Exception e) { // A generic catch block makes no difference in this case.
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also, as [Andreas pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62995153/adding-a-after-each-piece-of-data-in-arraylist#comment111399121_62995153), `readInput(input)` doesn't affect this program - so unless it has a bigger role to play, maybe look over this one again?

### `createLogic()`

Well it depends on the structure of your input file.

You're reading **line by line**, so if your input is like:

```
Max Amillion. 1234 South
John Doe. 4321 West
Mary Poppins. 101 Park
Acme Manufacturing Co. 9001 Main
```

Then of course there'll be no change to the output (because `createLogic` adds each *line* to the list). I imagine that you're actually trying to read each *token*, or better yet, maybe reformat your input file to make it easier for yourself.

Otherwise, your solution is to essentially refactor your code or input. You need a way to determine when you have a name, a street or an organisation. Any of the solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574041/read-next-word-in-java) will probably help you out.